# Phaser 3: text FontSize

Tags: fonts, font-size, phaser-framework

I want to make sure that this is the proper way to set fontSize for a text in phaser 3

```
this.add.text(posX, posY, "Text", { font: "12px Arial",fill: 'black' })
```

Because when I render this font in 12 px it appears to be extremely small compared to a the same options given in regular css... Am I missing something? Does it scale down according to the canvas size?

Answer (score 0):

which font you use and which size it is.
are different parameters

```
{
  font: 'arial,
  fontSize: '24px',
}
```